# Rails and mongoid: Validation is called on the referenced document upon saving/updating the referrer document?

Tags: validation, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, reference, mongoid

I have a model `Tracker that references_many Users`. 
Everything works fine, but for some business reasons, sometimes my 
Users model are in a situation were often they fails the validation 
rules (on purpose).

The problem is that I still need to update my Trackers in parallel of 
that. And to my surprise saving the tracker will trigger the 
validation rules for my User model as well... and obviously then the 
saving of the tracker fails.

I could save my tracker with `save :validate => false`, but I don't want 
to do that I have specific validation rules on the Tracker itself that 
I want to be respected. 
I also tried to play with deactivating callbacks but could not get it 
to work...

Help please !

Alex

Answer (score 1):

Ok, finally figured it out:

references_many :referees, :class_name => "User", :validate => false

This will do the trick !